# INSERT values in VARBINARY(MAX) column

Tags: sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I have a table with a `VARBINARY(MAX)` column and I've tried inserting values into this table but I can't.

The QUERY is:

```
INSERT INTO [I_RACEDB].[dbo].[tce_lineno]([lineNo] ,[testCaseName] ,[project])
 VALUES (<lineNo, varchar(250),> ,<testCaseName, varbinary(max),>,<project, varchar(100),>)

INSERT INTO [I_RACEDB].[dbo].[tce_lineno] ([lineNo],[testCaseName],[project])
     VALUES ('44','TestCase_TestCheck01_Mail_Validation','proj001')
```

The ERROR is:

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not
>   allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

How can I insert values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is self explaining.

Use `convert(VARBINARY(max), 'TestCase_TestCheck01_Mail_Validation')`

I.e.:

```
INSERT INTO [I_RACEDB].[dbo].[tce_lineno] ([lineNo],[testCaseName],[project])
VALUES ('44',convert(VARBINARY(max), 'TestCase_TestCheck01_Mail_Validation'),'proj001')
```

Comment: And you now have the first 30 bytes of data in the table. You might want to specify a length on that [`varbinary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx)