# H2 : how to insert/update a varbinary column

Tags: sql, database, h2

I'm newbie to h2, I tried to update a varbinary(255) column, using the responses of those questions :[Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567222/how-to-update-a-varbinary-field-with-a-specific-value), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293221/insert-values-in-varbinarymax-column), but it doesn't work I get this message:

> Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character: "test"; SQL statement:
>   UPDATE TABLE set COLUMN=CAST('test' AS VARBINARY(255)) [90004-176] 90004/90004

can anyone help ?.
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution my self, for those who face the same issue here is what to do :

```
UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN= FILE_READ('FILE.extension'));
```